# Prove the following limit using an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Prove $\lim \limits_{z \rightarrow i} (z^2) = -1$ using an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof. I am unsure of how to even begin.

Comment: For starters, please use MathJax to typeset your equations. You can find a guide [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: You can begin by looking at the definitions. When, by definition, is $$\lim_{z\to w} f(z) = L$$ true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and solve
$$
|z^2-(-1)|<\varepsilon
$$
taking into account that $z^2+1=(z-i)(z+i)$ and that, provided that $|z|<1$, $|z+i|\le|z|+|i|<2$.

It's essentially the same as proving that $\lim_{x\to2}x^2=4$ in the real numbers.